# Esta bien hecho el responsive del siguiente codigo?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Este codigo vendria a ser el codigo que haria "responsive" a la pagina. Me gustaria saber si esta bien hecho. Cabe destacar que por puera de los `@medias` pegue el estilo de css para en que en el caso de que se vea en pc se vea bien.

```
@media (max-width: 460px) {
  .red-text {
    color: #1E90FF;
  }
  img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
  h2 {
    font-family: Lobster, monospace;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .tamaño1 {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Lobster;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .thick-green-border {
    border-color: rgb(107, 170, 170);
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  }
  .smaller-image {
    width: 100px;
  }


  body {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
  }
  .fullCard {

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    background: linear-gradient(35deg,#CCFFFF, #FFCCCC  );
    font-family: Montserrat;

  }
  a{
    color: black;
  }
  a:hover{ 
    color: blue;
  }

}
```

Respectivamente repetiria dos @media: `@media (max-width: 700px)`, `@media (max-width: 600px)` con los mismos estilos que puse en el ejemplo anterior.

En el caso de que este mal me gustaria saber cual es la forma correcta de hacer responsive una pagina ya que soy autodidacta y cada sitio tiene su manera.

Comment: Tal y como está la pregunta es bastante subjetiva: hay diferentes formas de hacerlo y no hay una que sea la forma correcta. Va a depender del criterio del programador y las necesidades del proyecto. Por ejemplo, el diseño que presentas es _desktop-first_ (los estilos generales se aplicarán a las pantallas  grandes y los media queries  se usan con `max-width` para especificar estilos para pantallas más pequeñas como tabletas y móviles). Personalmente, prefiero el diseño _mobile-first_ donde se empieza con el móvil y se construye hacia pantallas más grandes (con media queries con `min-width`).

Answer (score 0):

No esta mal lo que estas haciendo, pero te muestro como hago a modo de ejemplo:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    clases para moviles // el maximo es 600px
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    clases para web desktop // a partir del minimo de 601px el estilo cambia y se adapta a escritorio
}
```

En mi caso utilizo este codigo para un sitio especifico, pero por lo general utilizo `Bootstrap` lo cual lo recomiendo porque te ahorras tiempo en escribir codigo que no esta mal aprenderlo.

Igualmente si quieres aprender mas te dejo el link de como trabajar con [medias queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries).

Bootstrap - https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Seguramente puedes simplificar el código si no usas el primer media query (construyendo los estilos de escritorio sobre los de móvil).

Comment: Joya, mil gracias!!!!

Comment: lo mejor para tener una pagina responsible es utilizar la siguiente libreria https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @marcosalbertosaavedrasanabr Hay muchas librerías de componentes web y Bootstrap es la más popular, pero ¿por qué es lo mejor para crear una página responsiva?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no tienes ningún error. Como decía un comentario allá arriba “va a depender del criterio del programador y las necesidades del proyecto”. Como programador autodidacta, mi código es el resultado de una combinación de al menos unas 50 personas que he visto programar por internet.

Cuando hago el resposive no lo dejo de último, después de cada cerrada de llave hago el resposive de ese elemento, tal vez parezca raro o erróneo, pero a mi parecer es más fácil de entender lo que quiero hacer.

**A modo de ejemplo:**

```css
div.contenedor {
   width: 700px;
   height: 500px;
   background: orange;
   text-align: center;
}

@media ( max-width: 600px ) {
   div.contenedor {
      width: 500px;
   }
}

@media ( max-width: 400px ) {
   div.contenedor {
      width: 95%;
   }
}
```

---

**By: Jeremy Fonseca**

Comment: Por favor [evita usar firmas en tus publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Cada aporte que hagas ya esta “firmado” con tu tarjeta de usuario en tu perfil.